# How to disable android spinner without graying it out?

Tags: android, spinner

Hi all  I am trying to show an Android spinner, but not show it as grayed out. I tried using setFocusable(false), which works fine on edit boxes, but not on spinners. I don't want the spinner to changeable unless I tell it to be. Basically I have a screen displaying data that I want to put in "update mode". Until the user has chosen to update the data, it should be view only.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up cheating a little. I got the background image before disabling the field, then set the background to that image after disabling the field.

```
    // Deal with spinners. I don't want to gray out the background
    // because it looks bad against our dark theme.
    Drawable d = type.getBackground().getCurrent(); // the enabled background

    type.setEnabled(enabled);

    // set all of the spinners back to the enabled background
    if(!enabled){
        type.setBackgroundDrawable(d);          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can create a custom selector and set it to the spinner background,
check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for the selectors